# Showing a form and confirmation page in a modal / overlay window

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I'm building a user registration modal / overlay form for the first time (using jQuery). I'm a bit of a jQuery noob, and I'm hoping you can help me with a question.

Presently, my form displays in the modal as it should. However, as it is right now, the modal closes on form submit and the user is taken to the 'full version' of the confirmation page.

Ideally, I would like the confirmation page to show in the modal as well.

This is just a standard HTML form, and the validation is handled server-side.

I'm assuming that I need to add some kind of onclick event to the form submit button, but I'm not sure what that should be. Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

For something like that, I'd generally have the submit button wired up to display a processing indicator of some sort, and then make a web service call. You would then process the response from the web service call, and update the dialog content to display either the confirmation details, or else an error message depending on the result.